# How to pass variable arguments to __android_log_print?

Tags: android, c, string, logcat, android-ndk

Original code that prints to stderr:

```c
extern "C" {
/* error: output error message */
void Error(const int error, char *message, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);

    if (error > 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError: ");
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "\nWarning: ");

    va_start(arg, message);
    vfprintf(stderr, message, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    fflush(stderr);
    if (error > 0)
        exit(error);
}

void main(){
    Error(0,"Problem %s in file", "sometext");
}

}//extern "C"
```

I modified my code to look like that. It should print to logcat.

```c
extern "C" {
#include <android/log.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>

/* error: output error message */
void Error(const int error, char *message, ...)
{
    va_list arg;

    va_start(arg, message);
    if (error > 0)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "HTS_API", message, arg);
    else
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "HTS_API", message, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    if (error > 0)
        exit(error);
}
void main(){
    Error(0,"Problem %s in file", "sometext");
}

}//extern "C"
```

Problem is that my code outputs: `'Problem |�;A.|�;A. in file'`

Calling the logger function directly, I will get the expected output.

`__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "HTS_API","Problem %s in file", "sometext");`

The expected output is: `'Problem sometext in file'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You define it as `Error` but call it as `error`. Also, it ought to be `int main`.

Comment: it was a typo and main is just a random function

Comment: Did you got any compiler warnings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__android_log_print` does not accept a `va_list` as a parameter.  It accepts a variable parameter list.

It looks like in the newest NDK they've added

```
int __android_log_vprint(int prio, const char *tag, const char *fmt, va_list ap);
```

which is what you want.  Formerly you'd have to fix this problem by either re-implementing  `Error` as a macro with variable argument list, or using `vsprintf` to format the error message in a buffer and then say

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "HTS_API", "%s", buf);
```